# How can I create a ticket from an email ? 

Tags: email, bugzilla

I am using Bugzilla and I was wondering if there is a way to create a ticket by sending an email to an account.

I looked around and I found that at some point there was a contrib/bug_email.pl, (that I think it did this) but its not there anymore on version 3.6 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been rewritten and promoted out of contrib!  It's now `email_in.pl` in the main directory.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the very thin documentation from Bugzilla:
http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/3.6/en/html/api/email_in.html

Some other help here to setup the system to route email to the email_in.pl script:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mozilla.support.bugzilla/Nf_CjGn6dME